Lazy creation of an asyncio event loop creates duplicates?
I have a number of modules that need to run under an asyncio event loop, though I don't know until runtime which modules will be loaded.  So at initialization, I want to make sure that there is one (and only one) event loop in effect.
I tried the following code.  I expected that the 'A' code block would create and use an event loop, and the 'B' code block would use the the same event loop:
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()  # use existing event loop
        logger.info(f'*** A using existing loop {loop}')
    except RuntimeError:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()    # ... or create and use a new one
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        logger.info(f'*** A creating loop {loop}')

    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()  # use existing event loop
        logger.info(f'*** B using existing loop {loop}')
    except RuntimeError:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()    # ... or create and use a new one
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        logger.info(f'*** B creating loop {loop}')

What I expected:
INFO:builtins:*** A creating loop <ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>
INFO:builtins:*** B using existing loop <ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>

Instead, it creates two event loops:
INFO:builtins:*** A creating loop <ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>
INFO:builtins:*** B creating loop <ProactorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>

(Ultimately, this results in a RuntimeError got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop.)
How do I dynamically create an event loop, if and only if it doesn't already exist?

get_running_loop returns the, well, you know, running event loop.  If there is no running event loop it raises the Exception.  Since you don't start the loop, it's not running.  So why don't save yourself trouble, and just create and set the event loop once and for all at the beginning of the application.  Until you start it, it does nothing and doesn't interfere with anything else.  When you're ready, just start it using one of the standard methods in the asyncio package.  You can also assign the created event loop to a variable and access it as needed, whether it's running or not.

@PaulCornelius After a good night's sleep, I came to the same realization.  Thanks for the confirmation.  P.S.: create an answer so I can give it the check mark?
